# Openlayers 6.4.3: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string 'bo'

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

When the parent `div` of the `Map` object is resized, it causes the stack trace below. I am trying to use [Openlayers 6.4.3 dist](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.4.3) in ExtJS 6.2 app.

```
    transform.js:117 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string 'bo'
        at Tt (transform.js:117)
        at e.getPixelFromCoordinateInternal (PluggableMap.js:744)
        at e.getPixelFromCoordinate (PluggableMap.js:730)
        at e.updatePixelPosition (Overlay.js:463)
        at e.render (Overlay.js:291)
        at e.dispatchEvent (Target.js:114)
        at e.renderFrame_ (PluggableMap.js:1174)
        at e.<anonymous> (PluggableMap.js:179)
```

Below is the relevant Openlayers and ExtJS code:

```
create_simple_map: function () {
    var mapbox_sat = new ol.layer.Tile({
        type: 'base',
        visible: true,
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets-satellite/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=mytoken'
        }),
        lyrControlOpt: {
            legendGroup: tr('base_layers', 'Base Layers', 'Base maps'),
            legendnodeid: 'mapboxid_sat2',
            legendTitle: "MapBox Street Satellite",
            bbox: null
        }
    });
    var geometery = new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-89.388446, 30.336019]));
    var feature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: geometery
    })

    var source = new ol.source.Vector({});
    var style = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgb(198,38,38)'}),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'rgb(198,38,38)'}),
            radius: 5
        })
    });

    feature.setStyle(style);
    var overview_point_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({source: source});
    overview_point_layer.setZIndex(2000);

    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            mapbox_sat
        ],
        target: 'overview_map_id',
        view: new ol.View({
            // projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            center: ol.proj.transform(
                [-88.793068, 33.456929],
                'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'
            ),
            zoom: 5,
            rotation: 0
        }),
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                collapsible: true
            })
        })
    });
    source.addFeature(feature);

    return [map, feature, overview_point_layer]
}
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.MyPanel', {
    
    afterrender: function () {
        // var overview_cont = Ext.getCmp('overview_map_id');
        var maps = create_simple_map();
        this.map = maps[0];
        var feature = maps[1];
        Utils.config.overview_map = this.map;
        Utils.config.overview_feature = feature;
        Utils.config.overview_point_layer = maps[2];
        this.map.setTarget(document.getElementById('overview_map_id'));

        Utils.config.overview_map_status = Utils.create_map_status(
            this.map);
    },
    resize: function () {
        this.map.updateSize();
    }
});
```

This error was not there in Openlayer 4. Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I create an overlay. It was because I used position keyword instead of `positioning` when I initiate the overlay.

Make sure first you used the right keyword then ensure you are passing either valid coordinate or undefined value.